# React Native expo : how to put link to Youtube video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, url, video, expo

I have a project where I must put some videos on my page. I didn't what they would be so I used this :

```
const video = React.useRef(null);
...
...

             <Video
                  ref={video}
                  style={styles.video}
                  source={{
                    uri: "https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4",
                    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g57_0gejMig
                  }}
                  useNativeControls
                  isLooping
                  onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => setStatus(() => status)}
                />
```

Howether it doesn't seems to work with url. Any idea?

Comment: Hi do you want this functionality to navigate to a video, or play the video in app?

Comment: To play the video in my app

Comment: Have you consulted this if it satisfies your use case  - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below implementation.

It uses a video id from a link that just pastes the ID of the Youtube video in the below code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import YoutubePlayer from 'react-native-youtube-iframe';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <View>
      <YoutubePlayer
        height={300}
        play={true}
        videoId={'84WIaK3bl_s'}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have this error with your response :                                                                 ./node_modules/react-native-youtube-iframe/dist/WebView.web.js:1:202
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-web-webview'
> 1 | Object.defineProperty(exports,"__esModule",{value:true});Object.defineProperty(exports,"WebView",{enumerable:true,get:function get(){return _reactNativeWebWebview.WebView;}});var _reactNativeWebWebview=require("react-native-web-webview");

Comment: @Louis install the react-native-webview dependency, `npm i react-native-webview`